# How can I keep a text selection inside the text area?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to keep the text selection when the [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) loses the focus.

For Internet Explorer and without any jQuery.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This isn't what the user expects to happen.

Comment: well, if i asked that probably I need it right? :)

Comment: It's a lot of code, so I don't have the time to write up an answer here right now, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592637/keep-text-selection-when-focus-changes for an idea of how to do it (that example uses jQuery, but only for the event handling -- the text selection stuff is all plain javascript).

Comment: You mean keep it visually, or just have CTRL+C copy into the clipboard the last selected text from the textarea?

Comment: I mean when i return to text box, the selection of text should be as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

If the selection needs to be visible only when the textarea has the focus, you could store the selected start and end, at `onblur` and at the next `onfocus` set it again.

Comment: the selection.createRange(); is empty after onblur event (Internet Explorer)