# How i would show dialog when i select any text on page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, text

I have web page full of text "lets say like that page". I don't mean "input element", i mean any text is been writing with

or , ...etc tags.

When I select some word(s), pop-up OR mini window OR dialog shows up with some options, lets say, link to email selected text or copy or print.

Its like when you are in any browser and select some text and then click Right Click on that selected text, and menu (integrated within your OS-window-) shows up.

i want the same story but dialog shows up right after i select. no need to do right click.

I'm reading "UI/API/1.8/Dialog" http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog and ".mouseup()" http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/ and also i found this nice article here http://motyar.info/blog/2010/02/get-user-selected-text-with-jquery-and.html

But still cant make the function I want. Maybe its easy and i don't see it :)

Appreciate your input!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected text on the mouseup event with some code like this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (event) {
    var text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    if (text != "") {
        //Use text in popup, etc... SAMPLE:
        alert(text);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than .mouseup() I think you want to use `.select()`:

http://api.jquery.com/select/

Comment: I think it wouldn't work with any text but input elements. "This event is limited to <input type="text"> fields and <textarea> boxes." from that jQuery.

Comment: You could style a textarea to look/act like a `<div>`. May not be the best solution, but could certainly work.

Comment: I could make textarea LOOK like div or any semantic tag from HTML5 but doesn't function like so. Users should be able to select ONLY not type any thing. There would be many of that "text" viewer tag <p> or <span>, ...etc. So to have textarea wouldn't be the ideal solution.