# Text deselected on right click in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, right-click

I want the user selection from a text area in my page. I have a context menu that user can use on right-clicking the selection. This is my code to retrieve selected content from a textarea in IE8,

```
var textComponent = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
var selectedText;
// IE version
if (document.selection != undefined)
{
textComponent.focus();
selectedText= document.selection.createRange();
alert(sel.text);
}
```

Now I notice that before allowing the blocked content (i.e. the Javascript) I can select a text in the text area and on right click it does not get deselected. 
But, when I allow the script, on right clicking the text that I selected gets deselected. Which is why I cannot retrieve the content.

I searched the web but didn't get any solution. Can anyone please tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the focus() method of the texbox or using the focus() method of any element on the page will clear the text selection.

Take a look here for a great answer:

[Keep text selection when focus changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592637/keep-text-selection-when-focus-changes)