# jquery color picker with execCommand call

Tags: jquery, color-picker, execcommand

Trying to call execCommand after color selection:

```
$('#picker').colorPicker(
    {           
      defaultColor:0, // index of the default color
      columns:13,     // number of columns 
      click:function(c){
             document.execCommand('ForeColor',false, c);    
      }
});
```

but nothing happens. If i replace execCommand with $('#output').html(c) i see that call is successful.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/YQQXV/12/

[ColorPicker plugin page](http://www.syronex.com/software/jquery-color-picker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a bit with you fiddle, incorporating an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817441/javascript-document-execcommand-cross-browser).

A more working example  of your fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YQQXV/11/).

It seems to me as if you forgot the `designMode` setting.

Comment: Hmm.. your example a little bit more complicated :) but anyway in your example entire string changes the color, i need to change color for selected part of the text only. i'm not sure that designMode should be specified because contentEditable is used.

Comment: mmh, i don't want to bombard you with more complicated JavaScript, but i can give you an example: http://help.dottoro.com/external/examples/ljcvtcaw/execCommand_4.htm - you can transfer the `ColorizeSelection` from the example to you you click-Handler.

Comment: Hi buddies, [look at my fiddle, it's also not perfect, but partially works.](http://jsfiddle.net/A8mfR/1/) If you examine the page in Firefox HTML Inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I), browser adds font tag internally. It's based on these two links: [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) and  [Preserve text selection in contenteditable while interacting with jQuery UI Dialog and text input at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315824/preserve-text-selection-in-contenteditable-while-interacting-with-jquery-ui-dial).

Comment: Florian, thanks for this example. probably i'll use it as workaround in case of execCommand ForeColor solution will not be found.

Comment: Stano, nothing changes in my Firefox 12.

Comment: Oh yeah, i figured out why it doesn't work with mouse. I call the saveSelection() method on keyup event, so you need to select with keyboard instead of mouse. But you can handle this also with the onmouseup event similarly :)

Comment: i see. it works and also can be used as workaround. but i want to clarify why my code doesn't work.

Comment: @user947668 [Your latest code preserves text selection and so it works:](http://jsfiddle.net/YQQXV/15/) Look, if you click on the color picker, the selection is lost, but as shown in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) it uses the `<select>` tag that preserves text selection, and so there is no need to remember and restore the range when an onclick occurs. I guess maybe some modal miniwindow could have the same effect?

Comment: you are right, browser loses selection after click on color picker. that was a problem. thank you very much for last fiddle, this is exactly what i need.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MS Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to pass a command ID as the first argument to execCommand.  Where is your ForeColor pointing to?

```
$('#output').html(c)
```

directly changes the inner HTML of the div with ID output, that's why it works.

Comment: ForeColor pointing to selected text.
I've added a button to show execCommand successful execution http://jsfiddle.net/YQQXV/12/

Comment: ForeColor is in the command identifiers list:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(v=vs.85).aspx